# Message property not getting deciphered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating angular modules and controllers as shown below,am lost as to why the output doesnt decipher the expressions even though I used "ng-app" and "ng-controller"
script.js

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);

myApp.controller = ("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Angular message";
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller="myController">
         {{ message }}
    </div>
    <div >
       10 +20 = {{ 10+20 }}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:-

```
{{ message }}
10 +20 = {{ 10+20 }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning the controller object to `myApp.controller` you should treat this as a method and pass controller name and definition as parameters.
Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Angular message";
});
```

Hope this works.

Comment: thanks,is there a way to check for such syntax errors

Comment: Try opening the browser's developer tool and the console errors (if any). Also you can integrate JS validators like (JSHINT, JSLINT) to your buid process (GULP, Grunt etc) which can notify you of any validation errors in your scripts.

Comment: Rahul - console errors are not that intuitive in this case,is there a link to integrate  JS validators into visual studio?

Comment: Try installing this plugin for JSLINT integration with visual studio.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ede12aa8-0f80-4e6f-b15c-7a8b3499370e

Answer (score 0):

Controller should be declared this way:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Angular message";
});
```

Comment: thanks,is there a way to check for such syntax errors ?

Comment: @user3682248, check the browser console (F12) for errors.

Comment: Console errors are also not that specific,is that how everyone debugs?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work.

`Working fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/GkarV/1004/

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of controller method is not correct. It is a built in method and it should be defined as below

```
myApp.controller('controller_name',function('dependency insert here'){
  //your logic.
});
```